# Emoji in Django admin form turns into question marks

Tags: python, django, unicode

In my Django app, I have a setup roughly like so: there is a Model class with a template field

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Message(models.Model):
    template = models.TextField(default=u'', help_text='Template string for message')
```

Then inside my view code I have something like

```
def view(request, message_id):
    message = get_object_or_404(Message, message_id__iexact=message_id)
    context = {...}
    return HttpResponse(Template(message.template).render(RequestContext(request, context)))
```

Then I create Message objects and modify their template field through the Django admin site.

I want to add emojis or other Unicode characters to one of my messages. I try copy-pasting an emoji into the text field, and save it, but on a refresh it's saved as a string of question marks instead of as the emojis.

I've double-checked that I haven't touched `DEFAULT_CHARSET` (should be UTF-8), and I have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the source of both the admin site and the public site. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Database used is MySQL

Comment: Then check [this](http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/03/31/using-emojis-in-django-model-fields) out. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link Pedram posted http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/03/31/using-emojis-in-django-model-fields ended up fixing things for me, turned out it was a MySQL setup issue.